# Skip duplicated entries on Call Log

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android Auto like app, where I want to show the call log using recyclerview and cards.

This is working fine, but the call log is showing all the logs. Lets say that if I have received 3 calls from Peter, I don't want to see 3 entries showing this, with one entry enought. This will be like doing something like "most recent contacts" or something like that.

When using the recyclerview and cards, I've created 3 classes to hold the contacts info: The custom adapter, the contact info, and the custom view holder.

This is the ContactInfo class:

```
public class ContactInfo {

    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String type;

    public static final String ID_PREFIX = "ID_";
    public static final String NAME_PREFIX = "Name_";
    public static final String TYPE_PREFIX = "Type_";
}
```

Then, in the fragment where I show the call log, this is what I do to display the logs:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phone_layout, container, false);
    ...
    ContactAdapter contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(DisplayCallLog());        
    ...
    return view;
}


private ArrayList<ContactInfo> DisplayCallLog() {

    ArrayList<ContactInfo> data = new ArrayList<ContactInfo>();
    int contactID = 0;
    String contactNumber = null;
    int logType = 0;
    String contactName = null;
    String contactType = null;
    ContactInfo cI;
    int resultLimit = 0;

    //Check access to Call Log
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        //Get phone numbers from call log
        Cursor cursorCallLog = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
        while (cursorCallLog.moveToNext() && resultLimit<6) {
            contactNumber = cursorCallLog.getString(cursorCallLog.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
            //We also get the call type: Incoming, Outgoing, missed
            logType = cursorCallLog.getInt(cursorCallLog.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE));
            resultLimit++;

            //With the phone number we search the ID
            String number = Uri.encode(contactNumber);
            Cursor cursorContactLookup = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                    Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                            number),
                    new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID},
                    null, null, null);
            while (cursorContactLookup.moveToNext()) {
                contactID = cursorContactLookup
                        .getInt(cursorContactLookup
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));

                //Get the contact name and phone type
                Cursor cursorContactDetails = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                new String[] {
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                                },
                                ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
                                new String[] {String.valueOf(contactID)}, null);
                while (cursorContactDetails.moveToNext()) {
                    contactName = cursorContactDetails
                            .getString(cursorContactDetails
                                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    int type = cursorContactDetails
                            .getInt(cursorContactDetails
                                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                    switch (type) {
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                            contactType = "Home";
                            break;
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                            contactType = "Work";
                            break;
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                            contactType = "Mobile";
                            break;
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER:
                            contactType = "Other";
                            break;
                    }

                    //Call contactinfo class and save into list
                    cI = new ContactInfo();
                    cI.id = contactID;
                    cI.name = contactName;
                    cI.type = contactType;
                    //cI.logType = logType;

                    //HERE: CHECK IF LIST DOES NOT CONTAIN CURRENT CONTACT
                    if (!data.contains(cI)) {
                        data.add(cI);
                    }
                }
                cursorContactDetails.close();
            }
            cursorContactLookup.close();
        }
        cursorCallLog.close();
    }
    return data;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that `cI` shows a string like this:

```
I/CONTACT_INFO: com.example_infodash.phone.ContactInfo@41c9e198
```

Where the last numbers are allways diferent even if the contact saved is the same. So it never finds the same contact in the list, even if is duplicated.

So my question is, how could I check if the contact saved is already in the list? I guess that the trouble in this case is because of the use of a custom class like ContactInfo.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the name?

Comment: @Doppie Yes I've tryed!

Comment: Maybe print the names to compare by hand, this should be the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem I'm having is that cI shows a string like this:
>
> I/CONTACT_INFO: com.example_infodash.phone.ContactInfo@41c9e198

Solution for this problem: Override `toString` method in `ContactInfo`

```
public class ContactInfo {

    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String type;

    public static final String ID_PREFIX = "ID_";
    public static final String NAME_PREFIX = "Name_";
    public static final String TYPE_PREFIX = "Type_";

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{name: " + name + ", type: " + type + "}";
    }
}
```

For ArrayList 'contains' problem, you have to override `equals()` in `ContactInfo`. Like this:

```
public class ContactModel {

    public String name;
    public String phone;

    public ContactModel(String name, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        ContactModel that = (ContactModel) o;

        if (name != null ? !name.equals(that.name) : that.name != null) return false;
            return phone != null ? phone.equals(that.phone) : that.phone == null;
    }

}
```

If you are in Android Studio you can create it automatically. Go to ContactInfo class, right click in it, choose:

```
Generate... -> equals() and hashCode()
```

Your equals() method:

```
 @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        ContactInfo that = (ContactInfo) o;

        if (that.name.equals(name) && that.id == id) return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the real problem I have is how to check if a contactInfo is already saved in the list. Any solution for this? How would you override the equals() method to achieve this?

Comment: I'm trying your code. Overriding toString() works fine to see in the log what is saved. But I still don't get to filter what numbers do I save. As you can see in my code, the relevant data to compare in ContactInfo is the ID and the NAME. Maybe I'm doing something wrong overriding the equals() method, so i would appreciate if you could modify your code applying my use case, this is, if the ID and the NAME are the same, then the contact exists.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it now. Should I modify hashcode() too?